# How to create cocoa pods?

Tags: cocoapods

I have a repo on github. I want to publish it as cocoa pod. I tried hard but couldn't find any frank tutorial.

http://guides.cocoapods.org/making/specs-and-specs-repo.html

teaches how to create spec file and how to update your existing pod , but doesn't tell how to create a new one.

while following https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/wiki/Creating-and-maintaining-a-pod , tutorial, i am facing errors after executing "$ pod push master" command, it says,

```
Pushing the `master' repo

remote: Permission to CocoaPods/Specs.git denied to HarshitDaftary.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Kindly help me.

Comment: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/wiki/Creating-and-maintaining-a-pod

Comment: @AvinashBabu , I followed the same link, kindly read my question properly...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60190643/656600

Comment: A detailed blog on "How to create custom CocoaPods" : https://dev.to/ankushppie/creating-custom-pods-in-swift-for-ios-a-step-by-step-guide-1p6g/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are apparently not (yet) a contributor to the `CocoaPods/Specs.git` repository. To add your pod to the public list you will need to fork that repo, push to that fork, and submit a pull request to have your addition merged into the upstream repository. See the "If you do not have push access to CocoaPods/Specs" section on http://guides.cocoapods.org/making/specs-and-specs-repo.html

Comment: so would i need to download that entire specs.git repo to my pc ? and then add my folder ???

Comment: @HarshIT Yes you need to fork that spec to your github account and than add your pod to that, after that you should create merge request to original spec repository. They will test it and than if it is okay they will publish.

Comment: @HarshIT "You do not need to fork the CocoaPods/Specs Master repo." 
https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/private-cocoapods.html